# printing constant string using ctypes results in segfault

Tags: python, ctypes

I am returning a constant string from a c function. using ctypes, when i try to print
it is resulting into segfault. I assume since its a constant string i dont really
need to alloc memory explicitly. Is my assumption correct?

test.c:

```
char *str = "constant string";
char* get_str() 
{
    return str;
}
```

test.py:

```
import os
import sys
import ctypes

from ctypes import *

lib = CDLL('./libtest.so')
s = lib.get_str()
s = ctypes.cast(s, c_char_p)
print(s.value)
```

---

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106     ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to properly specify function's ***restype*** (and *argtypes*) as explained in [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

*test00.py*:

```py
import sys
import ctypes as ct


LIB_NAME = "./libtest.so"


def main():
    libtest_lib = ct.CDLL(LIB_NAME)

    get_str_func = libtest_lib.get_str
    get_str_func.atgtypes = []
    get_str_func.restype = ct.c_char_p

    s = get_str_func()
    print(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Output**:

> ```bash
> [cfati@cfati-ubtu16x64-0:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q051536391]> python3 ./test00.py
> Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
> [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>
> b'constant string'
> ```

Comment: Did this answer your question?